# can i connect mp11se to kontakt for using vst with a A-Male to B-Male?

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard

or do I need a midi cable or something?

I do have a UR22 interface though

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can connect your Kawai MP11SE to your computer via a USB A to B cable.

No, you don't need a MIDI cable. But you *could* instead do it that way if you wanted. The UR22 has MIDI in/out so you'd just need to connect a MIDI cable from the MP11SE MIDI out to the UR22 MIDI in.

Then in your software—typically a DAW in which you'd be loading a Kontakt plugin—you'd select the MIDI device that you connected to (the Kawaii or the UR22).

The USB cable is probably the simpler choice but it doesn't really matter unless you have a specific reason that you'd want to use one or the other. For instance, if you had several MIDI controllers (say a keyboard and a foot controller) maybe you might want to chain them with MIDI cables.